# "Which do you want, A or B?" vs "Do you want A or B?"

Tags: word-usage, word-choice, difference

A) Which would you like, beef or chicken?

B) Would you like beef or chicken?

Are they the same?

Comment: The first version *might* more strongly imply *those are your only choices [and you **must** make your selection]* (so the second one might feasibly be more likely if the establishment serves *other* food besides beef- and chicken-based meals and/or only allows access to customers who purchase a meal). But in most contexts they're just different ways of asking the same thing.

Comment: Thank you and I apologize for my misinterpretation in my last question.  I thought you asked me something very strange but I took it wrong.

Comment: What context do you want to use these sentences in?  Are you a waiter (or writing in the character of a waiter)?

Comment: I don't expect a certain situation.  I only wanted to know if B is acceptable because I only learned A at school.